# makefile cant find .o files

Tags: c++, object, makefile

I'm very new to make files but after looking through a bunch of sources I cant find out why my make file is not working, it is for C++ and stated as below.

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-g -Wall -pedantic -ansi
SOURCES=commercial.cpp comRentals.cpp comSales.cpp property.cpp rentals.cpp residential.cpp resRentals.cpp resSales.cpp sales.cpp testPropertyA.cpp utility1.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
TARGET = runme

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -del $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET).exe
```

It is constantly saying the following when run from windows 7 commandline

```
C:\Users\Stat Phantom\Desktop\UNIVERSITY\C++\Assignment1\StartUpCode\TaskA>make
g++ -g -Wall -pedantic -ansi -c commercial.cpp -o commercial.o
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, g++ -g -Wall -pedantic -ansi -c commercial.cp
p -o commercial.o, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [commercial.o] Error 2
```

no idea what is happening here, help please, it is probably something very simple.

UPDATE: removed the included tags and added $@ to .cpp.o: however same error is occuring

Comment: You should not pass the header files to the compiler call, but use them with `#include "xxx.h"`

Comment: i do that in my .cpp file, reference's i saw had them there in the make file

Comment: Usually you let the compiler create a dependency file (`.d`) listing the headers using the `-MM` option family, and include this one in your makefile, to catch necessary recompilation because of changes in headers.

Comment: is that necessary? if so would that fix this problem

Comment: _"is that necessary?"_ Yes, if you don't want to be surprised why your stuff isn't recompiled if something was changed. As mentioned, you should remove this `INCLUDES=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.h)`, and leave it from the compiler call.

Comment: I have already removed it, will create dependency and see what happens

Comment: Can you update the error message as well? It still without file name after `-o`

Comment: pdated error message also, thought it was exactly the same

Comment: Can you show the output of this command: `g++ -v`?

Comment: g++ is not recognized as an internal command. I'm still new

Comment: You need to install c++ compiler first. Perhaps this link may help you: http://andres.jaimes.net/698/use-c-with-mingw-and-netbeans-in-windows/

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify output file name after `-o` :

Replace this:

```
.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o
```

with this:

```
.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Note: `$(INCLUDES)` also need to be removed.

EDIT:
After further checking, the actual issue seems to be simply because the OP does not have g++ installed. The relevant answer is available in this other SO question: [Compiling Small Gcc Project on Windows Using MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240422/compiling-small-gcc-project-on-windows-using-mingw)

Comment: thanks, I did install one when I installed code::blocks but I guess it wasn't fully installed